# Search condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

### country

CANADA
USA
SOUTH AFRICA

I need to write a query to check country name appearing in street or city is not country. The scenario is as follows:

I am having certain streets with country name like 'canada corner' where canada is country name. Earlier programmer had split the input as 'canada','corner' and used instr to check this

select * from country hrcm WHERE instr(:ls_name, lower(hrcm.country_name)) > 0

Similiarly other possible scenarios are like
'thousand street' where usa is country name in string 'thou'usa'nd'. But how to correct this.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in a tabular text format*.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Your previous version of this question didn't get an answer because you haven't improved it. People asked you for clarification but you didn't answer clearly. Instead you posted a duplicate question. If you want help you need to provide **sufficient information** for us to understand your requirements. With `[oracle][sql]` that usually means a simple table structure and some sample data, preferably as SQL, Of course, you don't have to do this. It depends how much you want an answer to your problem.

Comment: Table: 

country
-------
CANADA
USA
SOUTH AFRICA

I need to write a query to check country name appearing in street or city is not country. The scenario is as follows:

I am having certain streets with country name like 'canada corner' where canada is country name. Earlier programmer had split the input as 'canada','corner' and used instr to check this

select * from country hrcm WHERE instr(:ls_name, lower(hrcm.country_name)) > 0

Similiarly other possible scenarios are like
'thousand street' where usa is country name in string 'thou'usa'nd'. But how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Taken your question **very literally** as you have provided nowhere near enough information but just for fun here you go;

```
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(leftSide, '''', ''), ',',' ') = REPLACE(rightSide, '''', '')
```

This replaces all quotes and turns the commas into spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( strname ) AS 
  SELECT '''thousand''' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '''canada'',''tower''' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '''south'',''africa''' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  strname = '''' || REPLACE( :your_value, ' ', ''',''' ) || ''''
```

**Output**:

When `:your_value` is `usa`:

```
STRNAME
----------------
```

When `:your_value` is `canada`:

```
STRNAME
----------------
```

When `:your_value` is `south africa`:

```
STRNAME
----------------
'south','africa'
```

Comment: You have done opposite what I expected.  I have countries like USA, CANADA, SOUTH AFRICA in table. I need to check the 'Canada tower'  sho

Comment: @MKS The edit your **original** question to provide a [MCVE] including DDL and DML statements for your tables and example data and what your expected results are and your attempts to get them. We are not mind readers and if you do not specify how things will be how do you expect us to know.

Comment: Table: 

country
-------
CANADA
USA
SOUTH AFRICA

I need to write a query to check country name appearing in street or city is not country. The scenario is as follows:

I am having certain streets with country name like 'canada corner' where canada is country name. Earlier programmer had split the input as 'canada','corner' and used instr to check this

select * from country hrcm WHERE instr(:ls_name, lower(hrcm.country_name)) > 0

Similiarly other possible scenarios are like
'thousand street' where usa is country name in string 'thou'usa'nd'. But how to correct this.